# What is the purpose of "me" in "Je me suis trompé dans mon calcul."?

Tags: grammaire, sens

The sentence

> Je me suis trompé dans mon calcul.

can be translated as

> I've made a mistake in my calculation.

However, I don't understand the purpose of "me" in that sentence; for example,

je -> I

suis trompé -> have made

dans -> in

mon calcul -> my calculation

so if we didn't put "me" there, would the meaning change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confusion is due to the fact the most idiomatic ways to express it differs between French and English. However there are alternative forms with a closer structure in both cases.

> I've made a mistake in my calculation.

word by word translates to:

> *J'ai fait une erreur dans mon calcul.*

while

> *Je me suis trompé dans mon calcul.*

literally translates to:

> I mislead myself in my computation.

Answer (score 1):

This particular verb in French that means "to make an error", "to err", is a pronominal verb; it's just like that; you can use other verbs, but they are not  heard so often and they are verbal locutions instead of simple one word terms: "commettre une erreur", "faire une erreur". In a pronominal verb, just as in English, you have to use the pronoun all the time; there is no way to omit it. This pronoun, moreover, has nothing to do with the possessive adjective "mon"; that word is in the noun group not the verb group: you can replace it by all of these words in turn and say something a little different each time without changing the verb;

> ce, le, un, leur, ses, mes, tous ces, certains, etc. ("calcul" *or* "calculs" *according to gender*)

The conjugation is as follows ;

> je me suis trompé
>  
>   tu t'es trompé
>   il s'est trompé
>   nous nous sommes trompés
>   vous vous êtes trompés
>   ils se sont trompés

Answer (score 1):

It's often not a good idea to translate word for word. You made a mistake when you said "*suit trompe -> have made*".

You should have included "*a mistake*", but also "*me*".

> me suis trompé -> have made a mistake

In French, *to make a mistake* is ***se*** *tromper*. As Jlliagre said, it's reflexive because literally it means "*to mislead oneself*".

(It's a little more subtle than that, you should go see [all the meanings](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/se%20tromper) of "tromper" and "se tromper".)